# Firebase Auth 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' Failing "returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzam@290f989

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

**I can sign in users** added through the Firebase (FB) console, but I cannot add a user in the app.

I had a errors around the dependency versions which I have resolved, and also then on the API Key, so I added SHA1 and downloaded the new google-services.json into my app.

I'm not getting any exception or error, but its simply not working.

**project level build.gradle dependencies -->**

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

**app level build.gradle dependencies related to FB -->**

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
}
```

**FB Console Settings -->**

[image: Firebase Console App Config]
https://photos.app.goo.gl/HPBA5BjDMb2zV6gZ8

[image: Firebase Console Project Info]
https://photos.app.goo.gl/fuzuGZrMTFXPQ2cx8

**google-services.json -->**

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "364******410",
    "firebase_url": "https://scrumpoker1.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "scrumpoker1",
    "storage_bucket": "scrumpoker1.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:364*****7410:android:a*********7e565a",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.scrumpoker"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "364******410-***************3fqa18ar***8uejtr.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.example.scrumpoker",
            "certificate_hash": "4141********ce7744********521873****a7d0"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "364******410-***************55aq16hp***lbjrm5.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIza******sdR1ISugd70l9H1k**********pCo"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "364******410-***************55aq16hp***lbjrm5.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

**MainActivity.java OnCreate method -->**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
       mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

       emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
       passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);


       if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            try {
               showPokerActivity();
            } catch ( Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Login", "*****FAILED AT firebaseAuth getCurrentUser*****");
            }
       }


    }
```

As you can see below, registerModeActive is true and the app hits `Log.i("Create User With Email","********START EXECUTE******** " + registerModeActive);`. It then reaches out to Firebase and jumps to the `else` and logs `Log.i("Create User With Email", "********FAIL********");`.

**MainActivity.java Create User Method -->**

```
    public void registerClicked(View view) throws ParseException {

        } else {
            if(registerModeActive) {
                //Register
                Log.i("Create User With Email","********START EXECUTE******** " + registerModeActive);

                String email = emailEditText.toString();
                String password = passwordEditText.toString();

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Log.i("Create User With Email","********SUCCESS********");
                                    showPokerActivity();
                                } else {
                                    Log.i("Create User With Email", "********FAIL********");
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Authentication Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

            } else{
                //Login
...
```

**Logcat Output -->**

```
2019-04-14 10:39:34.498 13543-13543/com.example.scrumpoker I/Create User With Email: ********START EXECUTE******** true
2019-04-14 10:39:34.504 13543-13543/com.example.scrumpoker W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzam@290f989
2019-04-14 10:39:35.126 13543-13543/com.example.scrumpoker I/Create User With Email: ********FAIL********
2019-04-14 10:39:35.206 13543-13580/com.example.scrumpoker D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7f86f00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xafd8df90)
2019-04-14 10:39:35.628 13543-13580/com.example.scrumpoker D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa7f86f00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xafd8df90)
```

- Recreated my project in Firebase from scratch, twice.
- Regenerated my google-services.json for my project a number of times.
- Debugged my build.gradle dependency versions to resolve all conflicts.
- Added SHA1 and regenerated google-services.json again.
- Tried variations of mAuth.getCurrentUser in onCreate.
- Tried variations of handling email and password within the createUserWithEmailAndPasword function.
- Clean Build
- My project Web API Key on the console does not match the api_key in my google-services.json. I have tried manually switching them out in my google-services.json with no success.

Expected Result: New User Added to Firebase User Authentication.
Actual Result: Nothing happens.

Comment: Have set both Release/Debug mode for your project json?

Comment: No, I am very far from Release. I have been working with the default project setup, I enabled Email/Password as the sign-in method, and generated an SHA1. No other changes from default.

Comment: I set the following at the bottom of the JSON, no joy, still just failing.
    "configurations": {
      "Debug": {
        "buildOptions": {
          "define": [ "DEBUG", "TRACE"],
          "optimize": false
        }
      },
      "Release": {
        "buildOptions": {
          "define": [ "RELEASE", "TRACE"],
          "optimize": true
        }
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

It always fascinates me how the answer can be so simple! :)

**I forgot the getText()**

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditText.toString(), passwordEditText.toString())
```

**Replaced the above with**

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditText.getText().toString(), passwordEditText.getText().toString())
```

Mea Culpa!